# Map elements of a list as value of another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to map elements of a list as a value of a dictionary (in a list).

A list of dictionaries:

```
sample_list = [{'url': 'http://www.ohmynews.com/NWS_Web', 'title': ‘japan returns letter to sk politicians’}, {'url': 'https://www.ytn.co.kr/_ln/0101_201812261600067045', 'title': ‘sk lawmakers return letters’}, {'url': 'http://www.seoul.co.kr/news', 'title': ‘island opens up to the public’}]
```

A list:

```
source_list = ['ohmynews', 'YTN', 'SeoulNews']
```

I want to map elements of the `source_list` as a value of key `'source'` for each dictionary in `sample_list`

Wanted output:

```
output_list = [{'url': 'http://www.ohmynews.com/NWS_Web', 'title': ‘japan returns letter to sk politicians’, 'source':'ohmynews'}, {'url': 'https://www.ytn.co.kr/_ln/0101_201812261600067045', 'title': ‘sk lawmakers return letters’, 'source':'YTN'}, {'url': 'http://www.seoul.co.kr/news', 'title': ‘island opens up to the public’, 'source':'SeoulNews'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension.

```python
[d | {'source': source} for (d, source) in zip(sample_list, source_list)]
```

I used a combination of:

- zip to combine lists into one iterable
- `|` operator to merge dictionaries (Python 3.9). See [PEP 584 -- Add Union Operators To dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)

Comment: This worked magically, thank you!